# Projectile not showing all files under my Git project

Tags: project, projectile

I'm using Projectile to index a Rails 4 project.  When I use <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `projectile-find-file` to locate files using their file name, some files simply don't appear.

For example, I have a file located in `app/controllers/api/v1/test_controller.rb`, but typing <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `projectile-find-file` <kbd>enter</kbd>`test_controller`<kbd>enter</kbd> returns no results.

Is there a way to re-index the project, or figure out what's filtering out certain files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick answer is to invalidate the [projectile cache](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#project-files). When using `projectile-find-file` if you use <kbd>C-u</kbd> to send the universal argument before running the function, it will invalidate the cache before searching it. To match your example;

> <kbd>C-u M-x</kbd> *projectile-find-file*

There are a number of other functions in projectile that use the prefix argument, check for any that call `projectile-maybe-invalidate-cache` if the universal argument is present.

More generally though, projectile provides `projectile-invalidate-cache` which is by default bound to <kbd>C-c p i</kbd>.